# How to keep formula duplicating when a new line is created in google spreadhseet

Tags: google-sheets, formula, duplicate-data, code-duplication

I am trying to automatically copy formulas into a range of cell but whenever I try adding a new line it deletes the formula and I have to copy it again. I am trying to eliminate this. Is there a script that will allow this or anything similar?

Here is the formula: `=IF(E2=0,IF(D2>0,"not done",""),"")`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it in an arrayformula, like this:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E=0,IF(D2:D>0,"not done",""),""))
```

That'll extend when new rows are added.